# Python regular expressions - find 3 letter words containing only vowels

Tags: python, regex, nltk

As a part of some school work a task we have been set is to use regular expressions in Python to search through the nltk words corpus and find all 3 letter words that only contain vowels. The 3 letter part is easy but I'm having trouble with finding words that only contain vowels. I've tried a few different ways with no success which I will post below. If anyone can point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

```
 import nltk
 words = nltk.corpus.words.words('en')

 threeLetterConsonants = [w for w in words if re.search('[aeiou]', w)] 
 threeLetterConsonants[:10]
```

returns

```
['a', 'aa', 'aal', 'aalii', 'aam', 'Aani', 'aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'Aaron', 'Aaronic']
```

And I also tried:

```
 threeLetterConsonants = [w for w in words if re.search('[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]', w)]
 threeLetterConsonants[:10]
```

returns

```
 ['A', 'a', 'aa', 'aal', 'aalii', 'aam', 'Aani', 'aardvark', 'aardwolf', 'Aaron']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`re.search()` returns true if a *part* of the input matches (in your case, if the word contains *at least one*  vowel). If you want the *entire* input string to match, you need to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
threeLetterVowels = [w for w in words if re.search('^[aeiou]+$', w)]
```

As suggested by @pinkboi, you can put the "three letter restriction" into the regex as well:

```
threeLetterVowels = [w for w in words if re.search('^[aeiou]{3}$', w)]
```

Comment: Also, to make it 3-letter you need to add {3} instead of + after the group

Comment: @pinkboi: Right; he said that he's got this covered otherwise, but it's a much better idea to handle that in the regex itself. Thanks!

Comment: I was using [w for w in words if re.search('^[aeiou]+$', w) and len(w) == 3], did not realise that you could include the length in the regular expression.  Have now changed my code to [w for w in words if re.search('^[aeiou]{3}$', w)], thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following along with the other answer; if you need to limit the answers to only three letters, then in your Regex where you have ^[aeiou]{3}$ would limit it to 3 (and only 3) letters.